# Querying using Q objects

Tags: django, django-models, django-queryset, django-q

Hi I'm a newbie to Django. I'm trying to implement a search feature like this.

```
query_results = Shops.objects.filter\
                            (Q(shop_name__icontains=search_text)\
                            |Q(state__state_name__icontains=search_text)\
                            |Q(city__city_name__icontains=search_text)).distinct()
```

I would like to search `Shops` based on the `shop_name, state_name` and `city_name`. State and city fields are foreign keys.
For some `'Shops' state`and`city` are null. However, `shop_name` contains the `search_text`. So I'm not getting those '`Shops`' by running this query.
Any help on this is appreciated.

Comment: can you please post your models definition?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I suspect that when you use the `state__state_name` and `city__city_name` relations Django makes `INNER JOIN` to these tables.  Inner join removes the shop without existing relation from the result.

As a workaround for this issue you can try something like this:

```
states = State.objects.filter(state_name__icontains=search_text)
cities = City.objects.filter(city_name__icontains=search_text)
query_results = Shops.objects.filter(Q(shop_name__icontains=search_text)
                                    |Q(state__in=states)
                                    |Q(city__in=cities)).distinct()
```